# Função pipe() javascript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Como funciona a PIPE() do javascript (node.js)? Vejo ela muito no gulp e gostaria de saber como funciona a função diretamente no javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função [pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_pipe) que você viu no gulp na verdade vem do node.js.

A função *pipe* faz parte da API Stream do node.js. Muitas coisas em Node.js são Streams, como conexão HTTP, abrir arquivos, entre outros. Stream pode ser traduzido como *corrente* ou *córrego*, ou seja, a comunicação entre os nós são aos poucos, como um fino córrego. Por exemplo o YouTube, nós vemos os vídeos sendo baixado aos poucos. Aquilo se chama Streaming de vídeo, é onde o servidor vai mandando bytes do arquivo aos poucos, permitindo você assistir o vídeo. O mesmo se faz com qualquer tipo de arquivo, é melhor trabalhar com o server em streaming porquê evita milhões de usuários processarem o mesmo arquivo, sendo que o servidor pode ser mais inteligente mandando aos poucos o arquivo (em forma de Download de arquivos).
O node.js faz streaming melhor do que muitas plataformas.

No caso o *pipe* transforma algo *readable* para *writeable*, ou seja, ele transforma um fluxo legível para um fluxo de gravação ao coletar dados.